# Podcast app for iPhone, simple (few features), with “chapters” in an episode, and no censorship

Tags: ios, podcast

I need a podcast app for iOS (iPhone) that is simple to use, with few features to get in the way. I mainly want to play the latest episode of certain podcasts while out walking the dog.

Besides simplicity and reliability, two required features:

- Chapter support ([Podcast 2.0](http://adam.curry.com/html/WhatIsPodcasting20-28mcN0CfHFRjZRpkjpSf56jDCkMjTb.html)) to gracefully skip forward/backward
- Source a list of podcasts such as [*PodcastIndex*](https://blog.castopod.org/the-podfather-2-0-the-pioneers-strike-back/), to go beyond that of Apple, now that Apple has begun censoring their list for political correctness.

[Castamatic](https://www.castamatic.com/) met these requirements, but their new version 9 has been a quality failure.

Bonus features:

- Being controlled via Siri to “play the latest episode of such-and such”.
- Play faster at 110% or 115% of speed. The 125% and 150% offered by some apps is often too fast.